# provide permissions manually in django

Tags: python, mysql, django

i'm trying to create custom permissions , for every user(admin) we have several permissions like (`delete,creaet,post,update,view a specific part of the app`) , every users have multiple permissions

```
class UserPermission(models.Model):
    type_of_permission = models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    def __str__(self):
       return self.type_of_permission

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_permission'


class UserAccount(AbstractBaseUser):
   username = models.CharField(max_length=80,unique=True)
   active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
   permis = models.ManyToManyField(UserPermission)


class Post(models.Model):
   admin = models.ForeignKey(UserAccount,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   title= models.CharField(max_length=80)
```

for example we have `type_of_permission  = create new post , active = True` `type_of_permission  = delete posts , active = False` and so on ,and a user wants to delete a post , i want to filter users by `if request.user has delete posts active = False` then dont allow that user to delete the object

```
def delete_posts(request,id=id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Post,id=id)
    #how to filter if the requested user have permission to delete post
        obj.delete()
    #if not have permission then
    messages.error(request,'you dont have permission to delete')
```

is it possible to define permissions manually please ?

Comment: Have you tried xadmin? It is easy to set atom privileges by a superuser.

Comment: no , how is it ?

Comment: xadmin seems to let me grant or deprive user privileges to data on a webpage, with simple clicks.

Comment: let me check it , thank you